# pass an async function into another async function in rust that return different types of results

Tags: asynchronous, rust, future, lifetime

I would like to write an async function that takes in another async function as a parameter:

```rust
async fn do_sth_else(_ref: &str, _db: &DatabaseConnection) -> Result<i32, AppError> {
    // do something else
    Ok(15)
}

async fn do_sth<Fut>(
    _ref: &str,
    _db: &DatabaseConnection,
    _f: impl FnOnce(&str, &DatabaseConnection) -> Fut,
) -> Result<&'static str, AppError>
where
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<i32, AppError>>,
{
    // do something
    Ok("something")
}

// call the function
async fn call_both_functions(s: String, db: DatabaseConnection) -> Result<&'static str, AppError> {
    let result = do_sth(&s, &db, do_sth_else).await?;
    Ok(result)
}
```

when trying to call the function it gives error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:23:18
   |
23 |     let result = do_sth(&s, &db, do_sth_else).await?;
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected opaque type `impl for<'a, 'b> Future<Output = Result<i32, AppError>>`
              found opaque type `impl Future<Output = Result<i32, AppError>>`
   = help: consider `await`ing on both `Future`s
   = note: distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque types
note: the lifetime requirement is introduced here
  --> src/lib.rs:12:51
   |
12 |     _f: impl FnOnce(&str, &DatabaseConnection) -> Fut,
   |                                                   ^^^
```

Comment: Here's a [smaller minimal example on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e47ff218ff042e919c45933d98a4df3c)

Comment: It compiles if you add lifetimes like so `async fn do_sth<'a, 'b, Fut>( _ref: &str, _db: &DatabaseConnection, _f: impl FnOnce(&'a str, &'b DatabaseConnection) -> Fut,)` though that won't let you call `_f` on references of locals.